# Correlation when data ranges are different

Tags: correlation, python, finance, feature-scaling

I'm attempting to determine if there is a correlation between two variables - in this case prices and standard deviation. This is synthetic data to illustrate the problem.

The mean price values are 120,100 and the standard deviations are .0002 , .002

This code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[1, 120, .0002], [2, 100, .002]])

# Creating pandas dataframe from numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_step': data[:, 0] , 'mean_price': data[:, 1], 'standard_deviation': data[:, 2]})


t1 = go.Scatter(x=df['time_step'], y=df['mean_price'], mode="markers+text", name='chart1')
t2 = go.Scatter(x=df['time_step'], y=df['standard_deviation'], mode="markers+text", name='chart2')

layout = dict(title="", width=500,
    height=400,autosize=True,margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ))

fig2 = dict(data=[t1,t2], layout=layout)

iplot(fig2)
```

generates plot:

[image: s]

The values of the standard deviation in comparison to the prices are such that it is impossible to determine if this is any correlation.

If I increase the value of the standard deviation values by a magnitude of 20000:

df['scaled_standard_deviation'] = df['standard_deviation']*20000

and regenerate the chart:

```
df['scaled_standard_deviation'] = df['standard_deviation']*20000

t1 = go.Scatter(x=df['time_step'], y=df['mean_price'], mode="markers+text", name='chart1')
t2 = go.Scatter(x=df['time_step'], y=df['scaled_standard_deviation'], mode="markers+text", name='chart2')

layout = dict(title="", width=500,
    height=400,autosize=True,margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ))

fig2 = dict(data=[t1,t2], layout=layout)

iplot(fig2)
```

renders:

[image]

This is not a good method to determine if there is any correlation ? - Is there a standard method that if two variables are in different ranges then in order to determine if a relationship exists between the variables then scale the values to be in a similar range ?

Comment: (Pearson or Spearman) correlation has nothing whatsoever to do with the ranges (or the scale) of the variables: In fact, that's the whole point of dividing the covariance by the two standard deviations. This makes it hard to comprehend what you are trying to ask.  It has been pointed out to me by a colleague that in circumstances like this, where the data are discrete (or close to it), that you should be specific about what you mean by "correlation" in the first place, because the word has many different technical meanings.

Comment: @whuber "makes it hard to comprehend what you are trying to ask" apologies for my confusion. The crux of what I'm trying to ask is: if two sets of values are plotted on a graph and each plot a similar 'shape' but the scale of each set of of values differs how can a plot show these two values are correlated ? 

Or, to put another way if I took the set of price values in question : [120 , 100] and divided each value by 10000 to give [0.012 , 0.01] these two sets of values ([120 , 100]  and  [0.012 , 0.01] ) are highly correlated ? As they have same 'shape' but are each on a different scale.

Comment: Even if you cannot see it in the graph, the value of correlation will reflect the fact that the variables are correlated.

Comment: I still cannot fathom what you are doing or asking.  I see two plots, each with just four points.  What do you mean by "variable" and "correlation" in this context?